# get indexes of different elements from arrays with equal length using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two arrays with same length. for example

```
arr1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}.
arr2 {1,2,5,3,4,6,7,1,1,0}.
```

I need to get indexes of elements which are different:

```
{2,3,4,7,8}
```

How to do this using Linq?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022986/compare-two-arrays-of-different-lengths-and-show-differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest I could think of:

```
int[] diff = Enumerable.Range(0, arr1.Length).Where(i => arr1[i] != arr2[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - this outputs the indices generated by `Enumerable.Range`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
int[] arr1 = new[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
int[] arr2 = new[] {1,2,5,3,4,6,7,1,1,0};

var differentIndexes = arr2.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                           .Where(x => x.item != arr1[x.index])
                           .Select(x => x.index)
                           .ToArray();
```

Comment: If I swap `arr1` and `arr2`, this outputs `[2,3,4,0,0]` because the `1` appears multiple times.

Comment: @dbc You're right. Edited the code (which is a bit uglier now) to actually work for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to walk the arrays in parallel, compare the values, then output matching sequence indices:

```
        int [] arr1 = new int [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
        int [] arr2 = new int [] {1,2,5,3,4,6,7,1,1,0};

        var query = arr1.Zip(arr2, (i, j) => i != j).Select((b, i) => b ? (int?)i : null).Where(iptr => iptr.HasValue).Select(iptr => (int)iptr);
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList())); // outputs [2,3,4,7,8]
```

This doesn't require the sequences to be arrays.